# Monitor Windows Share

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to monitor connections to a windows share using C#, I am pretty sure it’s possible since you can see people connected to you from Windows Console Manager.

While I don't mind a solution using WMI I would prefer some alternate method.

What I mean by connections is when someone opens a share on the PC being monitored or a file in a share.

Comment: Belongs on server fault.

Comment: Not really , im writing a windows application that needs to do this , i know how to do it using normal system counters etc , but its not what i want

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using WMI, since it is designed for this very purpose.

Here is an MSDN link on Win32 shares & WMI implementation:

[Win32_Share Class - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394435%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Both WMI classes and performance counters exist for shares.

With WMI, you can see what sessions are open by share, using WMI associations. This is PowerShell code for a single share ("`Docs$`"):

```
$p = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Share -Filter 'Name="Docs$"').__PATH
Get-WmiObject -Query "Associators of {$p} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_ServerConnection" | Format-Table -auto ShareName, UserName,ComputerName,NumberOfFiles
```