# How to get notified when a folder is accessed?

Tags: c#, filesystems

I have a shared folder on my local machine. I want to get notified every time someone tries to access it. Could someone give me some hint on this?

I have checked the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher_members.aspx) class, it only provides events for change/creation/delete/rename of the contents **under** the folder, which is not exactly what I want.

I also tried to use the event log audition as shown [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399), but it is just not exactly what I want, either.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To get this information you need a [File System Filter Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/filterdrv/default.mspx).

So i just found the commercial vendor that offers a driver with a .Net API: [Eldos Callback Filter](http://www.eldos.com/cbflt/index.php)

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I thought about the File System Filter Driver. But kind of itimidated by the complexity. Since you mentioned it, too. I will take a look. Thanks. :)

Comment: a while ago i stumbled across a commercial product where they implemented such a driver and gave you a .Net API on the other side. But i just can't find it anymore. :-((

Comment: @Oliver - if you ever remember, please post here :)

Comment: @Cocowalla: A search today leads me to the wished result. Take a look into my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Oliver - this looks really good, though the pricing looks like it's on the high side. I'll check out the trial version

Comment: @Cocowalla: Yes the prices are really high, but if you see the complex problem they solved and how many programming hours needed i think the price is okay (if it works as expected, never tried it on myself!)

Comment: I just tried this out and within a few minutes it rebooted my machine, without warning. I think they have some reliability issues, so with regret I don't think I can use this :(

Comment: I let the sales guy who contacted me with the trial license know about my problem... wow, I've never known a sales guy to be so damn rude! Not getting a good impression at all, which is unfortuanate because I can't find anything similar :(

Answer (score 1):

Might also be something not exactly what you want but you can list connections using wmi, check [Monitor Windows Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448384/monitor-windows-share)

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know the filesystemwatcher fires a changed event if the files are only accessed and if the files are modified.

Comment: @smwikipedia says as much in the question so this isn't an answer.