# Get process which changed FileInfo.lastAccessTime or FileInfo.lastWriteTime

Tags: c#

Is it possible to find the process which changed the FileInfo.lastAccessTime or FileInfo.lastWriteTime of a File?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to intercept the access to a file in a .NET Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352826/how-to-intercept-the-access-to-a-file-in-a-net-program)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get notified when a folder is accessed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808722/how-to-get-notified-when-a-folder-is-accessed)

Comment: That's not the same question, that's about intercepting, this seems to be about looking after the fact.

Comment: I think you'd have to monitor all processes and watch for what file handles they create.  Which means you have to run as admin and would probably suck the life out of the machine.  So, IRL, no, not really.

Comment: @Oliver: Sorry that the question was unclear. Yes i dont wanted to know "if" and "when" a file is accesed, only which process it did.

Comment: @Will. I have implemented an Process Handle Monitoring, which checks every 5 seconds for the actual handles on Files from every Process. But as an example, i open an .txt with notepad, it does not lock the file i opened, instead i believe it loads the data of the file in the application cache, and so i dont see the handle on it.

Answer (score 1):

As David says, I do not think this is possible since I don't think this information is stored in any of the meta data for the files.
However, you might be able to do it in some way by turning on auditing, look at this link for more details (it's for XP but should be similar for Vista and 7):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310399

Comment: This sound like an option, but i see the problem that when i want to use the application on another system which didn´t activated this options, i´t would only work with alot of effort for the user. But good to know this option exist!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all Operating Systems do not track this information for IO performance reasons.

You can implement a file watcher using FileSystemWatcher.  Here's very simple example:

http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/11/file-watcher-utility/

And then get a process snap shot at the time from one of the event handlers

Comment: This could work, but lets say i have notepad.exe and word.exe open simultaneously and open the same file.txt with both applications, i cannot say it exactly wich of this processes made the lastWriteTime/lastAccessTime change.

Comment: Yep - you'd be screwed!!!  As I said - without OS support its a very hard problem to solve